# Phantom Faces and Normals

Tags: normals, faces

I have a mesh that had some trouble spots where I had extruded faces into the mesh and It left some extra faces that caused dark spots when I rendered it.

I've gone through and deleted all the faces but the dark spots are still there and when I show faces normals the direction indicator is there but no face to delete.
[image]

Comment: What happens if you try deleting them? They could be faces with no area, but they look more like vertices.

Comment: Enter Edit Mode > Select all faces with A key > Press W > Remove doubles

Comment: Anthony, I can't select them to delete them

Comment: Duarte I have tried that to no avail.

Comment: Did you use a boolean modifier before ?

Comment: Lemon, No I didn't use a boolean modifier but I did use a mirror modifier. I'm not sure if it caused the issue because I didn't notice it until I rendered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing doubles will merge vertices that are close together, in your case you still have duplicate vertices that are further apart than remove duplicates is configured to merge.

You can increase the merge distance used by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> or looking at the bottom of the toolbar region.

[image: remove doubles options]

You may also want to switch to vertex select mode to see where the extra vertices are and either delete them manually or move them closer so that remove doubles works, [snapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html) can be used to move them to the same location for merging.

[image]